# MySql как отсортировать по нестандартному формату даты

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с колонкой даты в формате `3/2/2023 в 5:05` или `31/1/2023 в 16:15`

Как сделать ORDER BY в таком случае?

Comment: Преобразовать из строки в дату, а потом сортировать. Очевидно же...

Comment: Трава зеленая, небо синее, спасибо, я и не знал

Comment: ^ а какие варианты? Я так понял, что у вас дата и время чего-то хранится в строковом поле (исходя из "... в ..." куда дата b dhtvz пишeтся не в формате удобном для сравнения строк (YYYY-MM-DD в HH:MM в общем-то сортировать как строки можно, а то что в примере - как-то нет)

Comment: можете еще преобразовать в лексикографические сравнимые строки, но в дату преобразовать будет проще :D